# Activiti BPM works with Eclipse neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, activiti, sap-cloud-platform

I am new to Java development and working with Activiti BPM.
I am getting started with them.

Activiti BPM says its verified with Eclipse Kepler. However I am using Eclipse Neon currently. I am trying to install Activiti plugin. It says it has to uninstall some plugins like Hana Cloud Plugins to continue with installation.

However I need both the plugins. So thought of using Eclipse Kepler to use Activiti BPM. But it supports till Apache Server 7 only ( and I have Apache 9 with Eclipse Neon )

Please suggest me a possible solution 
1) Use Different eclipses to work with Hana Cloud Platform tools, Activiti BPM (Is it possible to setup multiple Apache Servers in same pc like Apache7 and Apache 9)
2) Can be done in Same Eclipse

May be its a quite silly question, please guide me as i am beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of Course it does!!

I have installed activiti with Eclipse Neon and Apache tomcat 8/9 and it works pretty well.

I have also written a super detailed blog post on this, which starting from the setup, shows how to create not one but two fully working (although, simple) workflows.

You can check it out [here](http://codecramp.com/activiti-setup-eclipse/) and see if it helps.

Comment: @sravan No, I am sorry for the late reply. I was also stuck on this for a long time :P. Finally, after this answer, I hope, no one has to stuck in future.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this http://bpmn20inaction.blogspot.com.es/2015/08/activiti-designer-5180-released.html

There is a comment on the page saying this:

*"Hi Maxence, I've moved on to the Flowable project (http://flowable.org). You can find an updated Designer (with Mars and Neon support) on http://flowable.org/designer/update"*

I haven't had time to test it yet (I'll try later at the office)

I hope it helps